# Compare a list of integers with an integer to find the largest

Tags: java, list, loops, iterator

I need to write a code to returns true if the first argument contains a number greater than the second argument; returns false otherwise. Given that a list of integers(first argument) is compared to an integer(second argument). I must use Iterator to implement this function.

This is the code I have so far:

```
public class ListHasGreater {    
    public static boolean hasGreater(List<Integer> numbers, int number) {
        // write your code here
        Iterator<Integer> selectedNum = numbers.iterator();
        
        if (selectedNum.hasNext()){
            int result = selectedNum.next();
            while (result > number){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }  
    }
}
```

And I got this error `error: class, interface, or enum expected`

I'm not sure if my code is logically correct and don't know how to solve this error.

Comment: You can't just declare bare methods in Java. They need to be declared in the scope of a class (or enum or interface). In addition, your curly braces are not balanced. After fixing that, you'll need to look into the logic errors.

Comment: After I add the class and correct the curly braces, I got an error `error: missing return statement` but I did return the true/ false.

Comment: What if `selectedNum#hasNext` is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning from a conditional, you should also add a return statement at the end of loop.
Instead of
`while (result > number){return true;}` it should be `if(result > number) return true`

Comment: But if I return either true or false outside the loop. The truth value will become set and will have this errors `The result of [4, 78, 21, 5, 10] and 65 did not equal true. expected:<true> but was:<false>`

Comment: Try this 
`public static boolean hasGreater(List<Integer> numbers, int number) {
        Iterator<Integer> selectedNum = numbers.iterator();

        while (selectedNum.hasNext()) {
            int result = selectedNum.next();
            if (result > number) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }`

Answer (score 2):

The explicit use of iterators is quite an old way of programing, instead you can use a foreach loop and let Java convert this into iterators at compilation.

```
public static boolean hasGreater(List<Integer> numbers, int number) {

    for (int numInList : numbers) {
        if (numInList > number) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the for loop means? for numInList in numbers?

Comment: its called a foreach loop and it will iterate through each object in the list. Essentially the same as using an iterator must less code to write and must easier to read